# can we create a variable that can be modified from any functions in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, global

Hi want to know if there is a way to declare a variable that can be modified from any function without having to use the global keyword because i have a lot of functions modifing a certain variable and half of the time i forgot to put `global myvar` when creating a new function that modify myvar.

Comment: What you're describing is a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). When creating a new object you can initialize variables and use them in any method of that object.

These variables have `self.` prefix.

Comment: yes but with classes, i can't use the variables of a class outside the class

Comment: @rémicouturier: you can't? Why not?

Comment: Oh yes you are right, it works (and it also work with dictionnaries)

Answer (score 1):

yes this is the default behavior of python. But, there are some nuances you have to be aware of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

global_var1 = {}
global_var2 = 10
global_var3 = []


def manipulate_globals1():
    # this is the behavior you want
    global_var1['new_entry'] = 10
    global_var3.append(10)

    # this would fail
    # global_var2 += 10

    # but this works
    global global_var2
    global_var2 += 10


def manipulate_globals2():
    # here we create scoped variables with the same name as the globals
    global_var1 = []
    global_var2 = 5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(global_var1, global_var2, global_var3)
    manipulate_globals1()
    print(global_var1, global_var2, global_var3)
    manipulate_globals2()
    print(global_var1, global_var2, global_var3)
```

When you want to manipulate non-container variables inside a function you can do it this way:

create a file globals.py with content:

```
a = 10
b = 20
```

in your main/core file:

```
import globals

def manipulate_globals():
    globals.a = 20 
    globals.b = 30

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manipulate_globals()
    print(globals.a, globals.b)
```

Altough this is bad practice and you should not use globals inflationary

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to declare a global variable without the keyword global. The scope of the variable is determine by where it is declared in the code. To declare a new global variable, simply declare it outside of the scope of all other functions
For more help on scoping and global and local variables in python, check out https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Comment: Yes but as far as i understand, if i declare a variable outside of my function i can access its value from the function but i can't modify it.